# How template function chooses parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

template<typename T>
void Func( const T& val )
{
    std::cout << "const T& val\n";
}

void Func( const char* p )
{
    std::cout << "const char * p\n";
}

void Func( std::ostream & ( *manip )( std::ostream & ) )
{
    std::cout << "ostream\n";
}

int main()
{
    Func( std::endl );
    Func( "aaa" );
}
```

Observation:

1> Without `void Func( std::ostream & ( *manip )( std::ostream & ) )`, the line `Func( endl );` will cause compiler errors. I assume the issue is due to the template function `void Fun( const T& val )` can ONLY take a type of `T` but a function pointer.

2> Without `void Func( const char* p )`, the line `Func( "aaa" );` runs fine. I assume the reason is that the type `T` can be `const char*`.

Question> Are these correct arguments?

Thank you

Comment: Is the first function really called Fun and not Func, or is that a typo?

Comment: @happydave, I have modified the code and question.

Comment: In the second case without the `const char *` overload, `T` is deduced as `char[4]`.

Comment: @T.C., because the size of a pointer is of 4 bytes?

Comment: @q0987 No, because the string literal `"aaa"` is an array of 4 `const char`s.

Comment: @T.C., so if the code is `Func( "12345" );`, then the T is duduced as `char[6]` one character for the null terminator?

Comment: The *fun* part with comment upvote... whereas the second T.C's answer appears after the first q0987's question... (and so is misleading :/ )

Comment: Beware of the terminology, it is not a _template function_ but a _function template_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::endl` is itself a function template, so you cannot have template argument deduction for `Func` unless you actually specify a *function*. The following should work:

```
Func(static_cast<std::ostream&(&)(std::ostream&)>(std::endl));
```

Another way (thanks to @0x499602D2) is to specify the template arguments:

```
Func(std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
```

Comment: Why the cast syntax is NOT the following? `Func( static_cast<std::ostream&(*)( std::ostream& )>( std::endl ) );`

Comment: No, Kerrek explicitly said that `std::endl` is _not_ that. Did you actually ready the answer? See, for example, [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl).

Comment: @Useless, I have removed my comment. Thx

Comment: You can also provide the template arguments: `Func(std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>)`

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes, that's pretty cool. Please post it as an answer, since that's a nice alternative. (Or we can edit it in here if you don't mind.)