# Cast std::endl to a function pointer

Tags: c++, stl

This is a follow-up question to [How template function chooses parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142992/how-template-function-chooses-parameter)

[@Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143132/701092) proposed the following solution:

```
Func(static_cast<std::ostream&(&)(std::ostream&)>(std::endl));
```

I also found that the following code works for me too:

```
Func(static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>(std::endl));
```

**Question**> Which one is the preferred method?

Comment: Like arrays, functions and references to functions decay *implicitly* to pointers to functions.  And the function-call operator `()` works with both.  I tend to be explicit about creating and using function pointers (so the second one would say `&std::endl`), but it really is a matter of style.

Comment: Or simpler `Func<std::ostream&(std::ostream&)>(std::endl)`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Strictly speaking, the function call operator `()` works *only* with a function pointer as its prefix. If you give it an expression of function type or reference-to-function type, that expression will implicitly decay to a pointer before the `()` operator sees it. Using an expression of function type as the prefix to `()` isn't merely illegal; it's impossible. (Unless I'm missing some funky C++42 standard feature that makes it possible in some bizarre corner case.)

Comment: @Keith: No, a function does not decay when used as an operand of the function call operator, and using an expression of function type is perfectly legal.  5.2.2 starts with "A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.  **The postfix expression shall have function type or pointer to function type**."

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hmm. I'll check the standard and reply later.

Comment: Next sentence: "For a call to a non-member function or to a static member function, the postfix expression shall be either an lvalue that refers to a function (in which case **the function-to-pointer
standard conversion (4.3) is suppressed on the postfix expression**), or it shall have pointer to function type."

Comment: @BenVoigt: You're right. I need to stop assuming that C and C++ have the same rules. In C, the prefix must be of pointer-to-function type; the function-to-pointer decay is not suppressed. I wonder why it's different.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
template<class Sig>
struct reference_to_function {};
template<class R, class... Args>
struct reference_to_function<R(Args...)> {
  using type = R(&)(Args...);
};
template<class Sig>
using sig_t = typename reference_to_function<Sig>::type;

template<class Sig>
sig_t<Sig> pick_signature( sig_t<Sig> f ) { return f; }
```

then:

```
Func( pick_signature<std::ostream&(std::ostream&)>( std::endl ) );
```

which makes it explicit what I want to do, rather than a `static_cast`.

Maybe make a second version that takes a class type and a signature, and does it for methods as well.  (I cannot figure out how to make it work transparently for methods, and I think theoretically it cannot).